# Import CSV file in PHP and change it to bidimensional array

Tags: php, csv

What I am trying to do here is to create an array with the data i get from my csv file. I already tryied `str_getcsv`, but it didnt work correctly.

```
'Not Atribuited,"Agility Client","Servers AD","3 - Média","05/01/2015 09:13","3,0000000000","0","1"'
'Not Atribuited,"Rand Client","Servers AK","3 - Média","05/01/2015 09:13","3,0000000000","0","1"'
```

Those are two lines of example from the csv file, as you can see the first item comes outside quote, and there are commas inside other quotes that cannot be splitted.

The code ive tryied is this:

```
    $file = fopen("clientes/AMIL/Cliente_Prioridade.csv", "r");
    while(! feof($file))
      {
      $csv_line[] = fgetcsv($file);
      }

    fclose($file);
    foreach ($csv_line as $col) {
        $line = $col[0];
        $data[] = explode(',', $col[0]);
    }
```

This what the result looks like.

```
array (size=278)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      1 => string '"Acc Name"' (length=15)
      2 => string '"Subject"' (length=9)
      3 => string '"Priority"' (length=12)
      4 => string '"Date"' (length=23)
      5 => string '"Duration (Horas)"' (length=17)
      6 => string '"Open"' (length=8)
      7 => string '"Closed"' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Andrew Deco' (length=11)
      1 => string '"BANCO Example S/A"' (length=22)
      2 => string '"Novo Processo - Pessoas Autorizadas a Abrir Chamado"' (length=62)
      3 => string '"4 - Baixa"' (length=11)
      4 => string '"05/01/2015 10:20"' (length=18)
      5 => string '"6' (length=2)
      6 => string '0000000000"' (length=11)
      7 => string '"0"' (length=3)
      8 => string '"1"' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Not Atribuited' (length=14)
      1 => string '"Agility Client"' (length=18)
      2 => string '"Agility | Servers AD"' (length=25)
      3 => string '"3 - Média"' (length=11)
      4 => string '"05/01/2015 09:13"' (length=18)
      5 => string '"3' (length=2)
      6 => string '0000000000"' (length=11)
      7 => string '"0"' (length=3)
      8 => string '"1"' (length=3)
```

Comment: Please clearly demonstrate: 1) code used, 2) input given, 3) expected result, 4) actual result.

Comment: @deceze The expected result would be not to split the position 5 and 6, wich contains a quoted comma that gets it to split. The other info I updated on question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `explode` function just like

```
$i = 0;
foreach (file('path/to/your/file.csv') as $line){
    $array[$i] = explode(',', $line);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I added the code ive tryied and the output on the question. The problem with explode is that it splits on every comma, and i need it to not split quoted commas.

Comment: You can try to use _explode('","', $line);_ or use a diffrent seperator like |.
the Problem on this is, that you have to remove the " in the end and put one after Atributed.